# Run npm install or bower update on multiple repositories in folder

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm-install, bower-install

I have 3-5 repos in my parent /git folder that I have to individually run npm install, bower update, and grunt/grunt build. I was wondering if there is a way to where I can do it on the parent folder and it will run it for specific repos that I can specify. Similar for git commands there is a git multi, where I can do git multi pull/status/etc. for the repos I have listed in a .gitmulti file.

For example I can run a command like npm multi install, then it will run npm install on repos I have specified in a file. Similarly I would like to be able to do something like bower multi update and will run bower update on repos I specified.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of doing similar tasks with Grunt, here's how I would first try to approach your problem:

`grunt-exec` is a grunt plugin that lets you script out your shell commands in grunt.  To install `grunt-exec`, run `npm install grunt-exec --save-dev` in the parent directory for your projects.

Next, add the corresponding grunt config object to your `gruntfile`.  We'll keep things simple and do it statically:

```
exec: {
    foo: {
        cwd: 'foo/`,  //one of your projects
        cmd: 'npm install && bower install'
    }
}
```

Create additional targets within the grunt exec config object for each of your project directory.  Once that's complete, run `grunt exec` from the parent directory.